# $cordovaSQLite not working in ionic?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I have written the following in my controller

```
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(event, data){
        var db = null;
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'app.db' });
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");
});
```

and I have also installed sqlite plugin in my project.

but whenever i am running my controller i am gettin an error `$cordovaSQLite is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

To verify that both the Javascript and native part of sqlite plugin are installed in your application:

```
window.sqlitePlugin.echoTest(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Listen for *onDeviceReady* event and then use sqlite.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", yourCallbackFunction, false);
function yourCallbackFunction()
{
     // Sqlite API implementation here
}
```

Comment: can u also tell me do I have register my sqlite plugin anywhere else except .run() in my app.js file.

Comment: window.sqlitePlugin.echoTest(successCallback, errorCallback);                              this is giving error `Cannot read property 'echoTest' of undefined.`

Comment: Please check Sqlite installation

Comment: i have installed sqlite via `ionic plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage`

Comment: are u sure you are using ngcordova library in your module? and included the javascript file into your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Install sqlite plugin using the following command,

> cordova plugin add
>   https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage.git

Then in app.js page, **declare $cordovaSQLite** **in run function** & ADD your db code,

```
   .run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaSQLite,$timeout,$ionicLoading, $cordovaDialogs){
        var db = null;
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'app.db',location:1});       
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (id integer primary key, firstname text, lastname text)");

   })
```

Hope this will Helps!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In .run function you should initialize db like as:

```
            if (window.cordova) {
                // App syntax
                self.db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(CONFIG.DB_NAME);
            } else if (window.openDatabase) {
                self.db = window.openDatabase(CONFIG.DB_NAME, '1.0', 'database', -1);
            }
```